# Can I use word "shift" with curtain?

Tags: word-usage, collocations

> How your room would light up if you won't *shift* the curtains aside and let the sunshine come in.

Is the word *shift* correct when used about *curtains* in this context?

Comment: There is no mistake in grammar, though it is usual to refer to _drawing_ curtains rather than _shifting_ them. But isn't there a logical mismatch in your quotation?

Comment: @Kate bunting pardon. I didn't get you

Comment: @RichaMishra I edited your question - if it is not what you meant, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: Your sentence doesn't make sense.  But "shift" is OK -- "draw" or "pull" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: What they said. I also don't like _"come"_ - just _"let the sunshine in"_ is more idiomatic.

Comment: We would say: push the curtains aside, ***when using one's hands***.  draw the curtains implies some kind of tassel thing.

Comment: @Honzazidek it is absolutely fine sir good for me, thanks

Comment: The room would light up if the occupant _would_ open the curtains, not if they won't!  @Lambie I don't know where you're from, but in standard British English 'draw the curtains' does _not_ imply the use of a mechanical device.

Comment: @KateBunting I didn't say mechanical device. I said a tassel-type pull. Open is fine, yes.  Anyway, I would avoid would + would.

Comment: @Lambie My first sentence was to explain to the questioner what was illogical about his statement. I suppose I should have made two separate comments. Anyway, it's perfectly possible to draw the curtains with your hands.

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, [**shift**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shift) is used in the following sense:

> **b** : to make a change in (place)
>
> I shifted the bag to my other shoulder.

To expand on the idea, what you are actually doing is *shifting* the end of the curtain from its location on one side of the window to the other side—which also shifts all other pieces of the curtain along the way. This exposes the window behind it.

Such a term would not be misunderstood. Although, as said, there are also other terms. The most common is likely just *open the curtain*.